# Why iam getting this "UNDEFINED VARIABLE" error in php

Tags: php, html, mysql

i am very new in php, iam trying to figure it out why iam getting this error
Notice: Undefined variable: rowcount in C:\laragon\www\project1\index.php on line 19

The database connection is successful

the php code is this

```
<?php 

$sql = "SELECT * FROM users";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$rowCount = mysqli_num_rows($result);

if ($rowcount > 0){
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        echo $row['username']. "<br>";
    }
} 
else {
    echo "no results found";
}

?>
```

Comment: PHP variable names are case-sensitive: `rowCount` is not the same as `rowcount`

Comment: Typo.  PHP variables [are case sensitive](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php).